# How to inflate xml file on items of recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, hover, onclicklistener

I am using a library to hover on the items of recylerview but the listner for items is not working it worked before and also the problem is that --is the correct method to inflate the new xml file on another inflated xml file?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class LessonVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LessonVideoAdapter.LessonDataHolder> {

    private List<VideoList> slipList;


    public LessonVideoAdapter() {
        slipList = new ArrayList<>();
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 1", R.drawable.demo_one));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 2", R.drawable.demo_two));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 3", R.drawable.demo_one));
        slipList.add(new VideoList("Chapter 4", R.drawable.demo_two));


    }

    @Override
    public LessonDataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_card_view_video, parent, false);

        return new LessonDataHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LessonDataHolder holder, int position) {

        VideoList s = slipList.get(position);
        holder.bindSlip(s);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return slipList.size();
    }


    public class LessonDataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public BlurLayout samplelayout;
        private TextView nameOfSlip;
        private ImageView slipImage;
        private Context context;


        public LessonDataHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            context = itemView.getContext();
            nameOfSlip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.demoText);
            slipImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDemoVideo);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    {
                        Log.d("ashu", " clicked " + getAdapterPosition());

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void bindSlip(VideoList videoList) {
            nameOfSlip.setText(videoList.stringSlipName);
            slipImage.setImageResource(videoList.stringImage);
        }
    }


    public class VideoList {
        public String stringSlipName;
        public int stringImage;

        public VideoList(String stringSlipName, int stringImage) {
            this.stringImage = stringImage;
            this.stringSlipName = stringSlipName;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean that clickListener is not firing then post some more details about what you really want to do and xml of your viewholder and where you r putting above codes. Use logging to verify that click listener is firing or not

Comment: First check if the click listener is getting called or not. Also you have added condition for `getAdapterPosition`. I think inflating in such a way is not right.
Refer this library for hover view: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewHover

Comment: @AkshayChordiya  yes i am using the same library have u worked with it?

Comment: No I haven't used it. Can you give more details of issue your facing?

Comment: Please share your viewHolder xml. As per your above code click listener will fire only for the first item of recyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your xml and based on my understanding, I will suggest try this -

onCreateViewHolder() replace with this

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.abc_card_view_video, parent, false);
return new LessonDataHolder(v);
```

AND before itemView.setOnClickListener() put this -

```
itemView.setClickable(true);
```

I'm not sure about correct way to inflate xml but I'm using below code to inflate xml where ever I need except recyclerView adapter onCreateViewHolder() method callback -

```
View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.scanner_manual_entry, null);
```

If this solves your problem then please mark this post as answer.
Hope this helps